# Правильно ли я понимаю, что не все эти запятые нужны?

Tags: запятые

> "В ювелирном салоне мне удалось увидеть и перстень: он лежал на бархатной подушке(,) у всех на виду(,) в самом центре зала(,) на высоком постаменте(,) под стеклянным сферическим куполом."

Не могу разобраться, какие точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

*В ювелирном салоне мне удалось увидеть и перстень: он лежал на бархатной подушке у всех на виду, **в самом центре зала, на высоком постаменте, под стеклянным сферическим куполом**.*

Обстоятельства надо как-то сгруппировать и подобрать удобную для прочтения интонацию.

У меня два первых обстоятельства неоднородные, а дальше идет уточняющий ряд с перечислительной интонацией.

В то же время такая (или другая) группировка должна соответствовать контексту.

Comment: Спасибо. А если так: "В самом центре ювелирного салона, на высоком постаменте, мне удалось увидеть и перстень: он лежал на бархатной подушке у всех на виду(,) под стеклянным сферическим куполом."?

Comment: Многое, конечно,  зависит от контекста, но ваш первый вариант нравится мне больше. Это художественный стиль, вы как бы рисуете картинку, обходясь минимальным количеством слов  и простой грамматикой, но при этом создаете выразительный образ. Вот вы входите в салон и сразу видите перстень:  он лежит на бархатной подушке у всех на виду. Это ваше первое и самое яркое впечатление. А затем вы уже переходите к  другим деталям. Второй вариант в художественном плане выглядит слабее,  он  больше напоминает информационное сообщение. Поэтому важен контекст, без него варианты сложно сравнивать.

Answer (score 1):

Для пунктуационного разнообразия можно и лучше использовать тире, которое может ставиться, если можно условно подставить слово "это" (когда что-то расшифровывается или определяется значение предыдущей фразы):
*В ювелирном салоне мне удалось увидеть и перстень: он лежал на бархатной подушке у всех на виду — (это) в самом центре зала, на высоком постаменте, под стеклянным сферическим куполом.*

"*На бархатной подушке*" — место, "*у всех на виду*" — особенность расположения. Неоднородность — пауза между элементами не делается, запятую не ставим.
После тире перечисляются данные о местоположении, поэтому запятые.

Если переставить "*в самом центре зала*" в конец, то перед ним можно запятую не поставить (без паузы), рассматривая неоднородность:
*На высоком постаменте, под стеклянным сферическим куполом* — о месте относительно других предметов, а третье — о позиционировании в помещении.
*В ювелирном салоне мне удалось увидеть и перстень: он лежал на бархатной подушке у всех на виду — на высоком постаменте, под стеклянным сферическим куполом в самом центре зала.*

В начале предложения (перед подлежащим и сказуемым) при такой пунктуации звучит и оригинальный порядок слов:
*В самом центре зала на высоком постаменте, под стеклянным сферическим куполом находится перстень.*